# Why can't I assign python's print to a variable?

Tags: python, python-2.7, function-pointers, variable-assignment

I'm learning to program and I am using Python to start.  In there, I see that I can do something like this:

```
>>>> def myFunction(): return 1
>>>> test = myFunction
>>>> test()
1
```

However, if I try and do the same with `print` it fails:

```
>>>> test2 = print
File "<stdin>", line 1
  test2 = print
              ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Why is `print` different than a function I create?  This is using Python v2.7.5.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

[`print` is a statement](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/simple_stmts.html#the-print-statement), not a function.  This was [changed in Python 3](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3105/) partly to allow you to do things like this.  In Python 2.7 you can get print as a function by doing `from __future__ import print_function` at the top of your file, and then you will indeed be able to do `test = print`.

Note that with print as a function, you can no longer do `print x` but must do `print(x)` (i.e., parentheses are required).

Answer (score 3):

In addition to what BrenBarn said about the print function, note that `print` will not return a value. A statement of course will never return a value (which is why you see that error), but even as a function you will not get the value the function prints as the return value.

Instead, `print` directly writes something to the *output*, usually the console. If you want to store the value inside a variable instead, just assign whatever you wanted to print to that variable instead.