# How can i get a list of all built-in objects in python recursively?

Tags: python

how can i  get a list of all built-in objects in python recursively?

what i'm exactly searching for is a function like dir() which returns a list of objects instead of strings.

also, why does "dir(__builtins__.print)" fail in python's interactive mode with a syntax error?

thanks for your answers!

Comment: Does `__builtins__.__dict__` do anything useful for you?

Comment: Why recursively? It's not a particularly recursive problem.

Answer (score 4):

A dictionary of key value pairs: `__builtins__.__dict__`

Only the objects: `__builtins__.__dict__.values()`

These will give you a list of a dictionary you can iterate over to your hearts content!

**EDIT:** Not recommended, see below comment and that users answer

Comment: While this may work, it's generally a bad idea. `__builtins__` is not guaranteed to be the `__builtin__` module; sometimes it's the module's `__dict__`, and sometimes it's not even there.

Comment: @user2357112 Yep I agree, I've upvoted your answer and added a comment to mine.

Answer (score 1):

```
import __builtin__

__builtin__.__dict__.values()
```

Note that there is also, rather confusingly, an object called `__builtins__`. Don't use it; it might not work consistently:

> CPython implementation detail: Most modules have the name `__builtins__` (note the `'s'`) made available as part of their globals. The value of `__builtins__` is normally either this module or the value of this modules’s `__dict__` attribute. Since this is an implementation detail, it may not be used by alternate implementations of Python.

As for `__builtins__.print` giving a syntax error, it's because `print` is a statement, not a function. Python won't let you use the `print` keyword except as part of a print statement.

Comment: `print` is a function in 3.x, or with `from __future__ import print_function`.

Comment: thanks for your great answer, but why does \_\_dict__ not appear in dir(\_\_builtin__) ?

Comment: @jervis: ["Note: Because dir() is supplied primarily as a convenience for use at an interactive prompt, it tries to supply an interesting set of names more than it tries to supply a rigorously or consistently defined set of names, and its detailed behavior may change across releases."](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#dir)

Answer (score 0):

As to your second question, it's because in Python 2, `print` is not a function or any kind of object, but a statement.  See [this previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20767402/why-cant-i-assign-pythons-print-to-a-variable).